# Why put function declarations and definitions in separate files?

Tags: c++, syntax, header, declaration, definition

In codeacademy's lessons on functions, they teach you to use three files if you are going to call functions in your program:

- the `int main()` file, which i've found through trial and error is an indispensable part of the program part of a c++ program (i guess...), with a .cpp file extension
- a header file for DECLARING functions, with a .hpp file extension.
- a separate file with function DEFINITIONS, with a .cpp file extension

Would it work to both declare and define functions within the header file by itself and simply include them above `int main()`? To me having seperate files for declarations and definitions just seems like it would confuse matters in a larger project.

Comment: At work, I write programs that are 50+ thousand lines long. Imagine how long that would take to compile if every thing was in one file. I would get absolutely nothing done.

Comment: It's actually the opposite. Even a *moderately large* project may have dozens of .cpp files, with several calling functions that are defined by another source file. To call a function, it must be declared, but (apart from special cases like inline functions, which should not be used indiscriminately) no function can be defined more than once in the entire project. Using header files only for declarations allows each header file to be included by each source file than needs it. Defining functions in the header prevents that header being included by more than one source file in a project.

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah. The application I work on is ~600k lines of code and if everything was in headers it would be a nightmare to build. Currently a full build on a 20core/40thread machine takes ~5min, but it used to take 10+min and the reduction in compile time was largely realized by moving things out of headers and removing unneeded includes. It makes a huge difference in larger projects.

Comment: @dresherjm: [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) has some C++ files of more than dozen thousands of C++ lines. It works, and people are contributing to it. For example, its `gcc/go/gofrontend/expressions.cc` has 19711 lines in GCC 10.1, and they are hand-written and compiled daily.

Answer (score 4):

In a large project you often only need type and function declarations, not the definitions. For example in *other* header files. If all definitions were in the headers, then the combined result of including multiple other headers and their transitive includes would lead to *huge* compilation units. This *significantly* hurts compile times since the amount of code the compiler needs to process would explode to orders of magnitudes more than needed. It would also hurt link times since the linker would have more work to do in discarding duplicates included in many more object files.

You also easily run into ODR (One Definition Rule) issues unless everything is marked `inline`.

Answer (score 1):

In large projects, function declarations may be needed by many files, but the function definition should only be compiled once.  It is combined with all the places that need it at link time.

Answer (score 0):

A small C++ program can be (and often is made of) a single [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) of e.g. a few thousand lines of C++ code. In that case, you could have a single `myprog.cc` C++ source files (with several `#include`-s inside).

But when you work on a larger program, in teams, it is convenient to have several C++ source files.

Some C++ files are generated by another program (this is called [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) or [source to source compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler)) and could have a million lines of C++ lines. [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/) or [GNU Bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [TypeScript2Cxx](https://github.com/ASDAlexander77/TypeScript2Cxx) are capable of generating C++ code.

But if you work in a team of people like Alice and Bob, it is convenient to decide that Alice is responsible of `alice.cc` and Bob is writing `bob.cc`, and both cooperate on a common header file `header.hh` which is `#include`-d in both  `alice.cc` and `bob.cc`. That `header.hh` would practically define the [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) of the software project.

Read more about [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) systems (I prefer [git](https://git-scm.com/)) and [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tools (such as [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) or [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)).

Look for inspiration inside the C++ code of existing [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) projects on [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/) or [github](https://github.com/) or elsewhere (in particular, inside the source code of [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) and of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), both being major C++ compilers).

FWIW, in [GCC 10.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/gcc-announce/2020/000163.html) (of may, 2020) the `gcc/go/gofrontend/expressions.cc` file is handwritten and has 19711 lines of C++ code, so nearly twenty thousands lines. They are compiled daily. I do know the people working on that, they are brilliant and nice professionals. The biggest file of [FTLK](https://fltk.oth/) 1.4 is its `src/Fl_Text_Display.cxx` with 4175 C++ lines.

By personal experience, you might have a single C++ function of several dozen thousands lines of C++ (this makes practical sense only when that C++ code is generated), but then the compilation time by an [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) is dissuasive. You could adapt my [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) program to generate C++ files (it currently generates "random" C files with functions of "tunable" size) of arbitrary size. But C++ code generated by [Fluid](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/fluid.html) or [Qt Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-manual.html) might be quite large, and C++ code generated for [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) is often made of long but conceptually simple functions.

Nothing in the C++11 standard (see [n3337](https://github.com/tpn/pdfs/blob/master/C%2B%2B%20Standard%20-%202012-01-16%20-%20Working%20Draft%20(N3337).pdf)) requires several translation units. You might have (see [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) for an example) a single C++ file `foo.cc` of a million lines. And you could generate some of the C++ source code. The [Qt](https://qt.io/) project, the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler. Jacques Pitrat's book on *Artificial Beings: the conscience of a conscious machine* ISBN 978-1848211018 explain in many pages why such an approach is worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

There's kind of two answers to this question

1. why would YOU the programmer want to split things out into multiple .h/.hpp and .cpp files?

   I believe the answer here is it can help organization when your .cpp files become very large with a lot of code that may not be relevant to someone who needs to provide the functionality provided by the file. Here's an example:

   Let's say you have some c++ code that that display images on a screen. You as the person who wants to use that code are likely interested in the functions/classes exposed by that code which let you control that functionality. Maybe the code exposes the following helpful functions:

   - `WriteImageToScreen(int position_x, int position_y)`
   - `ClearScreen()`

   It can be much easier to look through a header file which only tells you what you are allowed to use rather than how all of that is implemented. It's very possible that implementing those two functions so that you can call them requires 1000s of lines of code and a bunch of variables and statements you don't care about. Not having to read that helps you focus on the important part of the code. The pieces you want to interact with.

   I've presented this example as if you were calling someone else's code but the same applies for your own code. As your projects get bigger, it can be convenient to have summaries of what each functionality a file exposes.

   Now that all being said, not everyone agrees this is the correct way to do things or that it is helpful.
2. why is it necessary for the compiler for things to be split out into multiple .h/.hpp and .cpp files?

   Just in case you aren't familiar with the term, a compiler is the program which turns your source code text into a program which your computer can execute.

   So why does the compiler need separate .hpp/.cpp files? Others have pretty much already hit the nail on the head with this one, but c++ compilers get confused if something is defined multiple times. If you put everything in a header file, then when you include that header in multiple files it will be defined multiple times. So in essence this circles back to the organizational question.

   I have seen programmers who just have a single main file and then all code is included directly to that main file during compilation

```
#include "SomeFile.cpp"
#include "AnotherFile.cpp"
// ...
#include "SoManyFiles.cpp"

int main()
{
   DoStuff();
}
```

I believe this is called a monolith build and it's not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a toy project, you can.

If you have a 1,000,000 lines of code, your build times will be horrid.

C++20 introduces modules, which should make the whole issue go away.

Other languages have tools that can extract an interface from a "module".
Hopefully, when C++20 arrives, tools will become available.

The only good reason to split an interface from an implementation is if there
are multiple implementations for one interface. E.g. VHDL, and will be available in C++20 modules. The pragmatic reasons are compilation speed and legibility.

Comment: I'm seeing the issue of build times as being one brought up frequently in the answers, writing "enormous" (well it only seems like that to me cuz the biggest program i've made has about 250 lines...) programs like that is a whole field i'm entirely unfamiliar with. So, if i had a single file with 1 million lines of code, how horrid would the build times be (an estimation is just fine, thanks...)

Comment: A million line project would be split up into hundreds or thousands of .h and .cpp files. I should have said "incremental" builds. When a modification is made, only the parts touched are recompiled, then the whole lot is linked. If a mod only touches one .cpp only one file is recompiled. If everything is in headers. all files that include it are touched, which cascades through the system. At the limit, changing one line could mean a million have to be recompiled.